# Can't run a Selenium test "could not start a new session"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, remotewebdriver

My friend sent me his code for Selenium tests using Selenium Grid, they work on his computer but not on mine. Here's part of the code file and pom.xml.

Chrome : 113.0.5672.93

Chrome driver : 113.0.5672.63

jdk : 1.8

Selenium Grid : 4.8.3

## Base class

```java
package Base;

import Pages.Login.LoginPage;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Base {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    LoginPage objLogin;

    public WebDriver initializeBrowser(String browserName) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

      if(browserName.equals("chrome")) {

            dc.setBrowserName("chrome");

        }else if(browserName.equals("firefox")) {

            dc.setBrowserName("firefox");

        }else if(browserName.equals("edge")) {

            dc.setBrowserName("MicrosoftEdge");

        }else if(browserName.equals("ie")) {

            dc.setBrowserName("Internet explorer");

        }else if(browserName.equals("opera")) {

            dc.setBrowserName("opera");

        }else if(browserName.equals("safari")) {

            dc.setBrowserName("safari");
        }
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444"), dc);

        return driver;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> vars;

    public void setUp(String strBrowser, String strEnv ) throws MalformedURLException {
        driver = initializeBrowser(strBrowser);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        vars = new HashMap<>();

        driver.get(strEnv);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public void loginUser(String strUserName, String strPassword) throws InterruptedException {
        ResourceBundle bundleLogin = ResourceBundle.getBundle("PageConfigFile.Login.Login");

        objLogin = new Pages.Login.LoginPage(driver);

        objLogin.loginToUser(strUserName, strPassword);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
}
```

## Test class

```java
import Tests.ProfilsTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Test extends Base {

    ProfilsTest objProfilTest;

    private Map<String, Object> vars;

    @BeforeTest
    public  void start() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        ResourceBundle bundleRec = ResourceBundle.getBundle("PageConfigFile.Env.Env");
        ResourceBundle bundleBrowser = ResourceBundle.getBundle("PageConfigFile.Browser.Browser");
        ResourceBundle bundleLogin = ResourceBundle.getBundle("PageConfigFile.Login.Login");


        String browser = "chrome";
        String env = bundleRec.getString("url");

        String username = bundleLogin.getString("test");
        String pwd = bundleLogin.getString("password");

        setUp(browser,env);
        loginUser(username,pwd);
    }
}
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sgtp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Tests</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Tests</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>


  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>8</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
  </parent>


  <dependencies>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->


 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.nordstrom.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>TestNG-Foundation</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-j8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
      <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openqa.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-rc</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-20081010.060147</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here's the error message I get when launching Test.java :

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'x', ip: 'x'
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: \[null, newSession {capabilities=\[Capabilities {browserName: chrome}\], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome}}\]
Capabilities {browserName: chrome}

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at Base.Base.initializeBrowser(Base.java:50)
    at Base.Base.setUp(Base.java:59)
    at Tests.Test.start(Test.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:65)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:381)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:319)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:645)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Dialect.lambda$bindAdditionalCommands$1(Dialect.java:80)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Dialect.bindAdditionalCommands(Dialect.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Dialect.access$100(Dialect.java:29)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Dialect$2.getCommandCodec(Dialect.java:54)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
... 29 more
```

Before that, when I launched the test, I had a blank GoogleChrome page opening with only an url like "data/".
I have tried to run the tests on the firefox browser to make it work but nothing appeared.
I have also tried to only launch some random test without using the remote web driver and it works so I am guessing the problem comes from using the remote web driver but I can't tell what is actually wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've tried to relaunch the program a couple of weeks later and it worked. Didn't even change anything in the code but anyways, good for me.

Answer (score 0):

try lower version of dependency and make sure to close driver, whenever your works completed or in any exception.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i tried to change the version but i get this error when doing `mvn clean install` :  Could not resolve dependencies for project sgtp:X:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.openqa.selenium:seleni
um-rc:jar:1.0-20081010.060147 (absent): org.openqa.selenium:selenium-rc:jar:1.0-20081010.060147 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached i
n the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: So i don't have this problem when I do `mvn clean install -U` but it doesn't solve anything either. Still have the session error. I do have the blank Chrome page opening tho, with url "data:,".

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem came from a dependency that wasn't getting installed only with `mvn clean install` because of some cache issue, to avoid that I had to force the installation by using `mvn clean install -U`.
Now when i launch my test, I still get the same error "could not start a new session." but I also have a blank google Chrome page opening with the url "data:,".